# Getting python to write to new line in a FIle

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple login system because I am bored and want to learn python, I am trying to store the usernames in a file but new usernames are just replacing the current one in the list.

```
#USENRAME UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD SYS

print ("WOuld you like to login or signup (login/signup)")
choice = input()

if choice == "signup":
    print ("Can you enter your username please?")
    username = input()
    with open('username') as f:

        if username in f.read():
            print("That Username already exists")

        else:

            f= open("username","w+")
            f.write(username + "\n")
            f.close()
```

Say if the first username I enter is "Dave" and then I close the program, the next username I register with being "Harry" The "Harry" will just replace the "Dave" In line one of the "usernames" file.

Comment: use `with open('username','a+') as f:`

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to open your file twice, but when you open it the first time what you you want to be able to do is append to what is already there.

```
with open('username.txt','a+') as f:
    if username in f.read():
       print("That Username already exists")
    else:
        f.write(username + "\n")
```

Try reading this if you're unsure.

https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html

Comment: Agree with answer. However, you do not need the line f.close(). This is taken care of by the use of the 'with' keyword. As soon as you are out of that block, the file will close.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, just forgot to remove it is all! Cheers for pointing that out